# Neovim doesn't recognize right curly braces ( } ) using spanish keyboard

Tags: vim, neovim, curly-braces

When I press ALT GR + ç, appears ^_ instead of }
[image]

*Edit: I can't either write characters like @ or #

Answer (score 0):

It seems that is a problem with neovim version 0.4 for windows. That's the current stable release.

**Updating to 0.5 pre-release** version should solve your problem.